# Android document scanner using opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am in the process of trying to develop a document scanner within an application of mine. As an example of what I want to achieve you can take a look at the Google document t scanner built into the Google drive app.

This allows

1. Detect edges
2. Manipulate into perspective
3. Display top down view of document

I have been looking at a number of 3rd party api to see if this can be achieved but they seem more focused on OCR. Which is not a priority of mine.

I have however stumbled across this [document scanner](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/)

Where it makes a document scanner using java open cv. Within the comments someone asked about the possibility of porting this to an android application. Apparently this is possible.

I have researched importing the open cv library within my IDE (android studio). This is also possible.

As I have not done this before I would be grateful if someone could help me identify any potential issues or alternative implementations which would help me achieve my goal.

I am eager to develop this myself with relying on 3rd parties where possible

Comment: have a look at this. https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo
link updated

Comment: @QadirHussain but does it have automatic edge detection?

Comment: @jean d'arme I don't think so it has automatic edge detection.

Comment: I implemented this and it does have edge detection. You have to us open CV in your project

Comment: @PowerMan2015 well, I reviewed documentation, but it's quite hard to read. Any suggestions where should I start? And will I have to dive into C++?

Comment: From what I remember it was a pain. No additional programming required. Look at adding opencv to the project and then add the scanner. There is a version fir android. Then simply pass the intent to the scanner

Comment: @QadirHussain,i use this library which one you mentioned but i get a issues to upload application playstore ,showing libpng issues .how to solve this?