# How to get information from driver license on scanning it in app camera in android studio

Tags: android

I am developing the functionality of scanning the driver license using camera and extract the information from it. I am scanning the driver license but i wont get data, i get only barcode number.

Please help me in code how to get information in driver license after scanning

Comment: what kind of libraries are you using?

Comment: You should use a 3rd party library which helps you scan a QR code or Barcode. 
Google has it's offical library or you can use another.

Comment: These libraries only scans barcodes not documents

Comment: Driver License? Many country has implemented RFID/NFC inside the card. If your phone have a NFC Scanner, you can make custom program by its API to scan the driver license. But, if there is no RFID/NFC inside the card. Use camera instead (plain photo, qrcode or barcode), take a pic and process it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OpenCv, Google vision or other computer vision library. QR code or Barcode libraries only scans Barcodes.

Check this answer : [Document scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909441/android-document-scanner-using-opencv)